# How to force close inactive Oracle sessions with ODP.NET

Tags: asp.net, connection-pooling, odp.net

asp.net 2.0 using odp.net 10.1.04 to connect to Oracle 10g.

Our web application has once a day this problem: ODP-1000 "Connection request timed out".

As we know, this is a memory leak problem, caused due open connections that don't get closed and disposed.

We have double checked our code and all connections after open are closed and disposed. All odp.net objects like OracleCommand, Oracledatareader are disposed after used.

On web.config, this is our connection string:

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="user id=xxxx;data source=XXXX;password=xxxxx;Pooling=True;Connection Timeout=15;Incr Pool Size=5;Decr Pool Size=3;Max Pool Size=300;Min Pool Size=10;Validate Connection=true;"/>
```

We have increased Connection Timeout to 60.

As we can't find in our code any unclosed connection, is there any way to close or destroy inactive Oracle sessions when conn.Open gets error "Connection request timed out"?

According to some information:
http://rainmanalex.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/odpnet-connection-string-attributes/

"The regulator thread is spawned every 3 minutes and closes up to Decr Pool Size amount of pooled connections if they are not used. "

Instead of waiting 3 minutes, is there any way to force close an inactive connection when getting error "Connection request timed out"?

Something like:

```
If conn.Open gets error "Connection request timed out"
Then
  Destroy inactive Oracle session
  Try again conn.Open 
End If
```

Comment: We are also running ASP.net with pooling connection for oracle, we haven't see inactive connection in pool caused problem. Some time we see "Connection request time out" because there are too many load and the oracle server reach the limitation. Try "SELECT * FROM GV$SESSION s where S.PROGRAM = 'w3wp.exe';" to see how many connection in server side. And here is another http://blog.ilab8.com/2011/09/02/odp-net-pooling-and-connection-request-timed-out/ useful link to explain the pooling connection in ODP.net

Comment: I think that every night a script should kill old sessions found in "select * from gv$session where program=w3wp.exe". Do you think it would mitigate "Connection request time out" error message?

Comment: I don't think this will help, because ASP.net will reuse the inactive connection which in the pool. But if your database is share by another application, it worths to check whether they are occupying too much connections. If you only have w3wp, I suggest you dig down a little bit to check whether Commander, Reader or connection were closed collectly. Please also check NumberOfActiveConnections and NumberOfFreeConnections perf counter.